# I have three tables which contains Parent,Child,Marks

Tags: sql-server-2008, union, union-all

I wanna merge Parent&Child table using join query and add Mark table using union query so is that possible to do?

In the Parent Table:

```
Id int(primarykey),
Firstname varchar(50),
Email  varchar(50)
```

In the Child Table:

```
Mid int(primarykey),
Mark1 int,
Mark2 int,
Id int(foreignkey)
```

In the Mark Table:

```
Uid int(primarykey),
Mark3 int,
Id int(foreignkey)
```

Finally the end result should be like this:

```
Id Firstname Mark1 Mark2 Mark3
-- --------- ----- ----- -----
2   John      59    78    89
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do Child.Id and Mark.Id relate to Parent.Id?  Can you provide sample data for Parent, Child, and Mark?  You can't use a UNION to get what you want.  UNION appends records into the result set from two sets with the same schema.  You would need to JOIN the Mark table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this just requires a fairly straightforward `join` between the tables?

```
select p.Id
      ,p.FirstName
      ,c.Mark1
      ,c.Mark2
      ,m.Mark3
from ParentTable as p
  join ChildTable as c
    on p.Id = c.Id
  join MarkTable as m
    on p.Id = m.Id;
```